# Transformation (rotation and translation) between 2 images

Tags: opencv, transform

I have this 2 images :

[image]

and

[image]

I want to calculate the rotation and translation between the two objects (the long vertical object is noise). How can I do that? I try estimateRigidTransform and I get a 3x2 matrix like this :

[[ 9.74271490e-01 -5.10741683e-02 2.52325933e+01] [ 1.05148056e-02 1.01445292e+00 -8.42995582e+00]]

I think that this matrix is like this :

[[ cos(angle) sin(angle) tranlation_X] [-sin(angle) cos(angle) translation_Y]]

But 9.74271490e-01 is different from 1.01445292e+00, so, what does it means?

Is estimateRigidTransform the best (only) solution?

Best regards,

Philippe

Comment: You may use `findHomography` to find the perspective transformation between two planes.

Comment: With `findHomography`, I need 2 arrays of points but I have 2 images. It is the same for `getAffineTransform` and `getPerspectiveTransform`.

Comment: `findHomography` using detector and descriptor in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Iterative Closest Point  (ICP).